# Gatling recorder doesn't capture content-type application/json

Tags: gatling

I used Gatling's recorder to record an interaction with my web application. When I tried to run the resulting simulation, by server complained that "MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found" for many of the requests. Apparently, the Gatling script did not save that most of the POST requests were made with `Content-Type: application/json`.

In the script, I can see that for a *different* request it set Content-Type to "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", so apparently the recorder will set the Content-Type under some circumstances. In the script, I edited the headers for the POST requests and added the Content-Type so that it read:

```
val headers_2 = Map(
    "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
    "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
    "X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")
```

When I reran the script, everything ran fine. So why did the Gatling recorder catch the Content-Type for one request, but not others? I'm using Gatling 2.1.7, if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you can provide a reproducer, I suggest you open an issue on Github: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues

Comment: @StephaneLandelle Thanks, I've now done so: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2826